# How to audit log member.createuser

Tags: asp.net

My ASP.NET application is Membership enabled and users with Administration Role can create other user with different roles.
Is there an way that i can maintain an audit log of user creation, so i can keep a track that which Administrator created which user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure the framework uses a stored procedure (forget the exact name, but it's named appropriately).  In that proc, add an insert to insert an audit record.